# Unable to Load Simple ListView In Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

I have one fragment contain list view, buttons and images.Buttons,images and other widget loaded correctly but instead of list view it shows only loading icon

public class ListDetails  extends SherlockFragment{

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ListView listView = (ListView)container.findViewById(R.id.list_view2);

            // Defined Array values to show in ListView
            String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                             "Adapter implementation",
                                             "Simple List View In Android",
                                             "Create List View Android", 
                                             "Android Example", 
                                             "List View Source Code", 
                                             "List View Array Adapter", 
                                             "Android Example List View" 
                                            };

            // Define a new Adapter
            // First parameter - Context
            // Second parameter - Layout for the row
            // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
            // Forth - the Array of data

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.listdetails_fragement, container, false);
    }
```

I have check other Button,Images are Loaded but List view gives error on my `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);` line [image]

here i provided my logcat error.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did:

Instead of doing everything in onCreateView(), I used onActivityCreated().

In onActivityCreated(), I just added this code:Here's the implementation:

```
public class Database extends Fragment {

    public ViewPager viewPager;
    private AllPagesAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = { "Tab1", "Tab2" };
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
            "Adapter implementation",
            "Simple List View In Android",
            "Create List View Android", 
            "Android Example", 
            "List View Source Code", 
            "List View Array Adapter", 
            "Android Example List View" 
           };
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View databaseview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.database, container,
                false);



        return databaseview;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView mListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.databaselist);

        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

    }

}
```

And the layout I used was :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/databaselist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="254dp" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newmainlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="database" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, here's the image for it:

[image]

Hope this helps .. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error because of this line..

```
ListView listView = (ListView)container.findViewById(R.id.list_view2);
```

here `listview` is null
change your code like this..

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listdetails_fragement, container,
            false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view2);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View",
            "Adapter implementation", "Simple List View In Android",
            "Create List View Android", "Android Example",
            "List View Source Code", "List View Array Adapter",
            "Android Example List View" };

    // Define a new Adapter
    // First parameter - Context
    // Second parameter - Layout for the row
    // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
    // Forth - the Array of data

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: and what about `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` in `adapter` is it working?

Comment: @SimplePlan yes it works..it returns the parent Activity context

Comment: @kalyanpvs and what about getActivity()?

Comment: @SimplePlan its the parent Activity object where this fragment to be added.if it's name is MainActivity then getActivity() returns MainActivity object

Comment: @kalyanpvs that's what i m talk in about so both solution are working over here.thnx

Answer (score 0):

Change `onCreateView(....)` with this

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View v=inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.listdetails_fragement, container, false);

     ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_view2);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                                         "Adapter implementation",
                                         "Simple List View In Android",
                                         "Create List View Android", 
                                         "Android Example", 
                                         "List View Source Code", 
                                         "List View Array Adapter", 
                                         "Android Example List View" 
                                        };


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
    return v;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me same error.:( any other solution?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch/com.androidhive.androidlistviewwithsearch.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ok you also go wrong in your `onCreateView(...)` go with my answer